# Refactor the Ruby CLI program

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I'm new to programming in Ruby.

1. How do I make the output show Revenue and Profit or Loss?
2. How can I refactor the following code to look neater? I know it's wrong but I have no idea how to take my `if profit` out of the initialize method.

```
class Theater

  attr_accessor :ticket_price, :number_of_attendees, :revenue, :cost

  def initialize
    puts "What is your selling price of the ticket?"
    @ticket_price = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts "How many audience are there?"
    @number_of_attendees = gets.chomp.to_i
    @revenue = (@number_of_attendees * @ticket_price)
    @cost = (@number_of_attendees * 3) + 180
    @profit = (@revenue - @cost)
    if @profit > 0
      puts "Profit made: $#{@profit}"
    else
      puts "Loss incurred: $#{@profit.abs}"
    end
  end
end


theater = Theater.new
# theater.profit

# puts "Revenue for the theater is RM#{theater.revenue}."
# I hope to put my Profit/Loss here
#
# puts theater.revenue
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: I think that [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) would be a better fit for this question.

Comment: @shawnb Well, the second part of the question maybe. Not the first.

Comment: You could start by removing all the redundant blank lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Theatre
  COST = { running: 3, fixed: 180 }

  attr_accessor :number_of_audience, :ticket_price

  def revenue
    @number_of_audience * @ticket_price
  end

  def total_cost
    COST[:fixed] + (@number_of_audience * COST[:running])
  end

  def net
    revenue - total_cost
  end

  def profit?
    net > 0
  end
end

class TheatreCLI
  def initialize
    @theatre = Theatre.new
  end

  def seek_number_of_attendes
    print 'Number of audience: '
    @theatre.number_of_audience = gets.chomp.to_i
  end

  def seek_ticket_price
    print 'Ticket price: '
    @theatre.ticket_price = gets.chomp.to_i
  end

  def print_revenue
    puts "Revenue for the theatre is RM #{@theatre.revenue}."
  end

  def print_profit
    message_prefix = @theatre.profit? ? 'Profit made' : 'Loss incurred'
    puts "#{message_prefix} #{@theatre.net.abs}."
  end

  def self.run
    TheatreCLI.new.instance_eval do
      seek_ticket_price
      seek_number_of_attendes

      print_revenue
      print_profit
    end
  end
end

TheatreCLI.run
```

**Notes**:

- Never use your constructor (`initialize` method) for anything other than initial setup.
- Try to keep all methods under 5 lines.
- Always try to keep each class handle a single responsibility; for instance, printing and formatting output is not something the Theatre class needs to care.
- Try extracting all hard coded values; eg see the `COST` hash.
- Use apt variables consistent to the domain. Eg: `net` instead of `profit` makes the intent clear.

Comment: That's very clean. Thanks bro!

Comment: Thanks :), much more to explain. But got busy, will try to add when I get time. Hope it will be of use to someone.

Answer (score 1):

Do not initialize the object with input from the user, make your object accept the needed values. Make a method to read the needed input and return you new `Theater`. Last of all put the if in separate method like `#report_profit`.

Remember constructors are for setting up the initial state of the object, making sure it is in a valid state. The constructor should not have side effects(in your case system input/output). This is something to be aware for all programming languages, not just ruby.